# Dataframe long to wide using two columns as variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I am wanting to reshape the following data from long to wide using both `port1` and `port2` as the variables of interest

```
            port1  port2     w_ret
date                              
2006-01-01    0.0    0.0  0.067991
2006-01-01    0.0    1.0  0.033219
2006-01-01    1.0    0.0  0.073324
2006-01-01    1.0    1.0  0.039730
2006-01-02    0.0    0.0  0.033616
2006-01-02    0.0    1.0  0.022452
2006-01-02    1.0    0.0 -0.024854
2006-01-02    1.0    1.0  0.020411
```

I wish for the rearranged data to look like this:

```
             0.00.0     0.01.0    1.00.0    1.01.0     

date
2006-01-01  0.067991   0.033219  0.073324  0.039730   
2006-01-02  0.033616   0.022452 -0.024854  0.020411
```

The numbers at the top resemble `port1` and `port2` numbers together. I am not sure what would end up going there when the correct code is used.

I have tried `unstack()` when making `port1` and `port2` an index with `date`and had a go at using `pivot_table`, but no luck in achieving this output.

Any ideas would be awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First join columns together, then [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with parameter `append=True` and last reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
s = df['port1'].astype(str) + df['port2'].astype(str)
df = df.set_index(s, append=True)['w_ret'].unstack()
print (df)
              0.00.0    0.01.0    1.00.0    1.01.0
date                                              
2006-01-01  0.067991  0.033219  0.073324  0.039730
2006-01-02  0.033616  0.022452 -0.024854  0.020411
```

Comment: thats clever.. :D